# Creating ASP.NET vNext NuGet that can target multiple frameworks

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a NuGet package that will work on ASP.NET vNext (Desktop and CoreCLR) as well as .NET Framework 4.5.

I've looked at http://json.schemastore.org/project for the schema but it appears that there is no guidance on what "frameworks" are acceptable.  This is my current project.json but I am not sure if it is correct.

What values for "frameworks" is possible?

```
"frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0",
                "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0",
                "System.Xml": "4.0.0.0",
                "System.Xml.Linq": "4.0.0.0"
            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22231",
                "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Xml.ReaderWriter": "4.0.10-beta-22231",
                "System.Xml.XDocument": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Globalization": "4.0.10-beta-22231",
                "System.Diagnostics.Debug": "4.0.10-beta-22231",
                "System.Diagnostics.TraceSource": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22231",
                "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Linq.Parallel": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.0.10-beta-22231",
                "System.IO.Compression": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Reflection": "4.0.10-beta-22231",
                "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Threading": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Reflection.Extensions": "4.0.0-beta-22231"
            }
        },
        "framework45": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.4"
            }
        },
    }
```

Comment: What framework do you want to target?

Comment: I want to target .NET Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can target other frameworks: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Core/project.json

Use `net45` for .NET 4.5

Comment: Can you target .net40?

Comment: Yes, you can target net40.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in VS2017RC with MSBuild?